# How to execute call after each search

Tags: vim

In Vim, I'd like to execute a particular function each time a new search is run.  What I'd really like is an event that could trigger an autocmd each time the search register is changed but I am aware of no such event.

An alternative approach would be to remap the / command to something that executes the search and then calls my function.  This seems to be the easier solution but I guess I don't know how to remap this type of operation and preserve the search string.  Would I need to remap / to a function and then within that function use getchar() to read in the search pattern, then pass that to the real search function?  Would doing so cause unintended consequences in the :s function?

Perhaps there's a different approach I should be taking?

As a side note, my application is that I want to set up a separate highlighting group for the search pattern if it's under my cursor so regular search would have an equivalent of the IncSearch highlighting group.  When there are many matches, I find it difficult to see where my cursor is when moving through them using / and n.  I have added my function in a remap of n and it works as I want, but I can't get it to work for the first search.

======= Edit 1: the type of thing I *think* I'm looking for =========

It would be nice if I could do something like this

```
:nnoremap / /:call MyFunction()<cr>
```

or

```
 nnoremap /  :call MySearch()<cr>
 function! MySearch()
   normal! /
   call MyFunction()
 endfunction
```

but this doesn't work because the substitution happens before the user types the search pattern.  I'm not sure how to wait until the search pattern is typed and pass that to the function or something.

Comment: In such cases what I like to use is a recursive macro.

First fo all you must `:set nowrapscan`
then use the search operation to search the text you want to modify with /

Start recording your macro with `qq` then `n` then the commands/functions like `:call MyFunction()`
Then `q`

and add the call to macro inside the macro with:

    `let @q.='@q'`

Finally go back to start of buffer with `gg` and replay the macro with `@q`

The macro will search for the expression you type and apply the commands recorded until last reference was matched. Remember do not forget `:set nowrapscan`

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. Can you explain how to remap / in this case?  What I'd like is for search to work the usual way (without having to use the @ symbol), but every time the search register is changed, for my function (which does not change the buffer) to run.

Comment: You could try [this plugin](https://github.com/ivyl/vim-bling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, romainl, for pointing out that plugin.  It has a similar goal to what I am doing and reading their code I learned that they had figured out a way to remap the search function.  I implemented something similar and it works!

Here's the solution:

```
# function to replace default <enter> expression
function MySearch()
  if getcmdtype() == '/'
    return "\<cr>:call MyFunction()\<cr>"
  else
    return "\<cr>" 
  endif
endfunction

:cnoremap <silent> <expr> <enter> MySearch()
```

Basically instead of remapping `/`, we remap the `<enter>` that completes the search command.  Enters get typed at other times as well, so we check whether this is a search and execute the function only then.

There may be other solutions as well but this one is working great and I learned something new.  Thanks!